# How to add data in dataframe dynamically in r

Tags: r

I am creating some variables dynamically and then trying to store them in a dataframe `row wise`. But, I am getting only the last value in my dataframe. Previous values are replaced with new ones.

```
threshold <- 0.5
path_length <- 2

for (i in 1:3) {
  assign(paste('x', i, sep='_'), 1)
  assign(paste('y', i, sep='_'), get(eval(paste0("x_", i, sep=""))) + (threshold * 0.2) - (path_length - 1.3)) 
  assign(paste('z', i, sep='_'), get(eval(paste0("y_", i, sep=""))) * i + 2)
  
  df_1 <- data.frame(i=i,
                     x=get(eval(paste0("x_", i, sep=""))), 
                     y=get(eval(paste0("y_", i, sep=""))), 
                     z=get(eval(paste0("z_", i, sep=""))))
}
```

I am getting this output

```
  i  x   y   z
1 3  1  0.4 3.2
```

My expected output

```
  i  x   y   z
1 1  1  0.4 2.4
1 2  1  0.4 2.8
1 3  1  0.4 3.2
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to `rbind` new data to original data frame instead of refreshing original data.

Comment: Something like this?   `df_1 <-  rbind(i, get(eval(paste0("x_", i, sep=""))),
        get(eval(paste0("y_", i, sep=""))),
        get(eval(paste0("z_", i, sep=""))))` but getting the same output (my previous) but columnwise

Comment: Like this, `df <- rbind(df, df_1)`, `df` should be initialized as an empty data frame `df <- data.frame()` out of the loop.

Comment: Yes, it works. But I am getting the output of only `1 column`. But, I need 4 columns! `[1] 1.0 1.0 0.4 2.4 2.0 1.0 0.4 2.8 3.0 1.0 0.4 3.2`

Comment: Why do you need to `assign` first and then `eval` and `get` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
threshold <- 0.5
path_length <- 2
df <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:3) {
  assign(paste('x', i, sep='_'), 1)
  assign(paste('y', i, sep='_'), get(eval(paste0("x_", i, sep=""))) + (threshold * 0.2) - (path_length - 1.3)) 
  assign(paste('z', i, sep='_'), get(eval(paste0("y_", i, sep=""))) * i + 2)
  
  df_1 <- data.frame(i=i,
                     x=get(eval(paste0("x_", i, sep=""))), 
                     y=get(eval(paste0("y_", i, sep=""))), 
                     z=get(eval(paste0("z_", i, sep="")))
                     )
  df <- rbind(df,df_1)
}
df
```

Output

```
  i x   y   z
1 1 1 0.4 2.4
2 2 1 0.4 2.8
3 3 1 0.4 3.2
```

It can be more efficient like

```
i = 1:3
x = rep(1, 3)
y = x + (threshold * 0.2) - (path_length - 1.3)
z = y * i + 2
df <- data.frame(i,x,y,z)
df
```

Comment: `paste0` only accept two parameters, e.g., `paste0("~/dynamic_csv",".csv",sep="")` is fine.